# Error with simply Maybe funtion

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads, option-type, sanctuary

### Background

I am trying to help someone in StackOverflow with a question regarding Futures and Maybes and Eithers. My first approach is to have a simple function that takes in a `Maybe` and computes something.

### Code

I am using Sanctuary, but this is equivalent to Ramda or any other library.

```
const S = require("sanctuary");

const transform = S.map(
  S.pipe( [ S.trim, S.toUpper ] )
);

S.Maybe.Just( ["  heello", "  world!"] )
  .map( transform )
```

### Problem

The problem is that this *simple function* is failing with the error:

> TypeError: S.Maybe.Just(...).map is not a function

### Question

I am confused to say the least. I know that Maybe is a Monad, and that Monads are Functors. Each Functor must have a `map` method, but somehow Maybe.Just ( which is a Maybe type ) doesn't?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Maybe` is a functor and has a `fantasy-land/map` attached, and it's consumed using `S.map`. Also, you build a `Just` using `S.Just` or `S.of (S.Maybe)`:

```
const S = require("sanctuary");

const transform = S.pipe ([ S.trim, S.toUpper ])

const maybeTransformed = S.map (transform) (S.Just (['hello', ' world!']))
```

Comment: You can also build a Just using `S.Maybe.Just`, which is the approach I am using. Thanks!

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix Nope, `S.Maybe.Just` seems to be for internal use of Sanctuary. Don't use it: it doesn't type check.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks for the heads up. Because the code works with either `S.Maybe.Just` and `S.Just`, I thought I could use it as well. Turns out it's no that way!